# SQL - Is it possible to sort columns by other columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
3       2       1
```

Is it possible to return the columns in order of ASC? 1>2>3

```
 Column3 Column2 Column1
 1       2       3
```

Comment: the ,3,2,1 are values inside of each column ? or just are ref to the column ?

Comment: mysql or sqlite? you can just set the columns order when you do the select

Comment: There is no built-in sql level support for ordering based on columns. Period. You have to manually set the order, but to do that you already need to know their values. If you already know their values, then there is no point in executing the query.

Comment: @wu4m4n They are values in the columns any integer.

Comment: @Dekel I'm using android studio.

Comment: Dekel's question was not about what development tool you use, but which rdbms product you use: mysql or sqlite. These have different syntax and characteristics.

Comment: @Shadow Sqlite, I thought he was talking about using the built in tools in those rdbms

Comment: There is no way to do what you expect on any RDBMS

Comment: What if your table has two rows, (3, 2, 1) and (4, 5, 6)?  Then what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in sql level support for ordering based on columns. Period. You have to manually set the order, but to do that you already need to know their values. If you already know their values, then there is no point in executing the query.

What you can do is to turn the columns into records using `union` and sort them that way. The output will be in a different format, but you can achieve the dynamic sorting. But you have to know in advance the names of all columns:

```
select col1 as val, 'col1' as colname from yourtable
union
select col2, 'col2' from yourtable
union
select col3, 'col3' from yourtable
order by val asc
```

`val` field gives you the value, `colname` fields tells you from which column the data came from.